# Angular 10 Dynamic Nested Form output to html table

Tags: angular, html-table, nested, formarray

I have an Angular form with dynamic nested form using FormArray. I got the idea for the the nested form from another post. I'm trying to output the nested form to a html table with rowspan. I think I have the structure worked out correctly but when I try to render the nested form to a table, the header is pushed to the right and the first column becomes the column for the entire output.

I have a stackblitz entry here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4zjniz?file=src/app/app.component.ts

When the form first renders, it shows this:
[First time on component image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0nmY.png)

Then as I click on Add Seat Emp and Add Skill, the header gets pushed over like this.

[Added parent and child image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouCjs.png)

How can I get the header to stay to the left and render correctly for the table? Thank you in advance.

Here is my html code: (app.component.html)

```
<div class="control-section e-rte-custom-tbar-section">
  <div >
    <form [formGroup]="empForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div formArrayName="employees">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th rowspan="{rowSpan}">Emp #</th>
            <th rowspan="{rowSpan}">First</th>
            <th rowspan="{rowSpan}">Last</th>
            <th rowspan="{rowSpan}">Remove Emp Action</th>
            <th>Skill #</th>
            <th>Skill</th>
            <th>Exp</th>
            <th>Remove Skill Action</th>
          </tr>

          <ng-container *ngFor="let employee of employees().controls; let empIndex=index">  
            <tr [formGroupName]="empIndex">
              <td>{{empIndex}}</td>
              <td><input type="text" formControlName="firstName" placeholder="first"></td>
              <td><input type="text" formControlName="lastName" placeholder="last"></td>
              <td><button (click)="removeEmployee(empIndex)">Remove Emp</button></td>

              <div formArrayName="skills">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let skill of employeeSkills(empIndex).controls; let skillIndex=index">
                  <div [formGroupName]="skillIndex">
                    <tr>
                      <td>{{skillIndex}}</td>
                      <td><input type="text" formControlName="skill" placeholder="skill"></td>
                      <td><input type="text" formControlName="exp" placeholder="exp"></td>
                      <td><button (click)="removeEmployeeSkill(empIndex,skillIndex)">Remove Skill</button></td>
                    </tr>
                  </div>
                </ng-container>
                <tr><button type="button" (click)="addEmployeeSkill(empIndex)">Add Skill</button></tr>
              </div>
            </tr>
          </ng-container>
        </table>
      </div>
    
      <p>
        <button type="button" (click)="addEmployee()">Add Seat Emp</button>
      </p>
      <p>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </p>
    
    </form>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the code: (app.component.ts)

```
  import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
  import { FormGroup, FormArray, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  title = 'Nested FormArray Example Add Form Fields Dynamically';

  empForm:FormGroup;


  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) {

    this.empForm=this.fb.group({
      employees: this.fb.array([]) ,
    })
  }


  employees(): FormArray {
    return this.empForm.get("employees") as FormArray
  }


  newEmployee(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      skills:this.fb.array([])
    })
  }


  addEmployee() {
    console.log("Adding a employee");
    this.employees().push(this.newEmployee());
  }


  removeEmployee(empIndex:number) {
    this.employees().removeAt(empIndex);
  }


  employeeSkills(empIndex:number) : FormArray {
    return this.employees().at(empIndex).get("skills") as FormArray
  }

  newSkill(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      skill: '',
      exp: '',
    })
  }

  addEmployeeSkill(empIndex:number) {
    this.employeeSkills(empIndex).push(this.newSkill());
  }

  removeEmployeeSkill(empIndex:number,skillIndex:number) {
    this.employeeSkills(empIndex).removeAt(skillIndex);
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.empForm.value);
  }


}


export class country {
  id: string;
  name: string;

  constructor(id: string, name: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
<div *ngFor="let employee of employees().controls; let empIndex=index">
```

is messing with the markup for the table because it's adding an extra `div`.

You can change it to this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let employee of employees().controls; let empIndex=index">
```

and then the extra `div` won't be added. I tried that out in your Stackblitz and it seems to work fine now with that change.

[image]

Read more Angular's `ngContainer` in the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#group-sibling-elements-with-ng-container).

Deeper into the structure there is another problem coming from more `div` elements nested inside the table. You can replace them all with `ngContainer`, it also works for `formArrayName` and `formGroupName`. But then there is another problem of nested `tr` elements inside a `tr` elements. The nested `divs` and `tr` element are all invalid HTML for tables.

After replace all `div` with `ngContainer` and remove the nested `tr` element you have another problem.

[image]

So now I think you might need to rethink the solution a bit. A quick idea might be to add a nested table for the skill rows. Now it looks like this:
[image]

Maybe it doesn't look like you want it, but it's at least a valid HTML table now, maybe some CSS can make it look better if you change the alignment of employee data cells. But I don't think it's possible to have one table that will show all employees and their skills in the same table, I think you will need to use a nested table like in my example, or think of a different solution for this.

I've forked your Stackblitz and added the nested table [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-te9awg?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Comment: Hi Nathan. Thank you for the information on ng-container.  I updated the code to use ng-container on both the parent and child FormArray. The parent array is now aligned correctly with the header but the child is only occupying the first column and the remaining child column is pushed to the right.  I've updated the stackblitz with the updated code and links.  [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4zjniz?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I understand the problem, but it's difficult. I have updated my answer with more details and suggestions, but I think the end result is that maybe you need a different solution for this.